# Fluent API Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, fluent-interface

I have a database that has three tables structured as follows:

```
Table 1: Product
Columns: ProductID, PK
         SKU,       PK
         Name

Table 2: ProductImages
Columns: ImageID    PK
         SKU

Table 3: Images
Columns: ImageID    PK
         ImageContent
```

Ignore for a moment that table `ProductImages` looks to be in a many-to-many relation except that the Unique PK constraint is forcing to be one-to-one and therefore an unnecessary one-to-many-to-one table (it's an existing database).

I would like to have the following `POCO` entity class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Assume `Image` is also an entity in my entity model.

I am using `Entity Framework 5.0` with code first and the `Fluent API` and I am going nuts trying to figure out how to write the `ProductMap` class (which derives from `EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>`). Specifically the relationship mappings.

The rendered SQL should look like Entity Framework's version of the following:

```
select p.SKU, p.Name, p.ProductID, I.ImageID, I.ImageContent
from Products p
inner join ProductImages si on p.SKU = si.SKU
inner join Images i on i.ImageId = si.ImageId
```

Any help that anyone can provide will be met with heart felt appreciation.

Comment: Shouldn't SKU be the primary key for ProductImages?  If this is the case then it would seem that you would want a collection of Product images, that has a collection of images, contained within your product class.

Comment: You're not going to make this unless you're willing to deceive EF by telling it that Product only has SKU as primary key. (a many-to-many mapping is possible). But that may cause exceptions because in reality SKU is probably not unique in Product.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem until I started using [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://www.google.by/search?q=entity%20framework%20power%20tools&aq=f&oq=entity%20fram&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Using it you can generate clear entities like a business objects and mapping classes.
Good article that helped me to create amazing data access layer: [Reverse Engineer Code First](http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/)

And i think mapping should looks like:

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap ()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ProductId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Product");
        this.Property(t => t.ProductId).HasColumnName("ProductID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.Products)
            .WithMany(t => t.Images)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("ProductImages");
                m.MapLeftKey("ProductID");
                m.MapRightKey("ImageID");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already used this tool. The 2 problems are the Products.SKU - >  ProductImages.SKU does not exist in the database (and therefore cannot be reverse engineered out) and the second problem is even if it could, the mapped POCO would be Products.ProductImages[0].Image. I need the relationship to be flattened to Products.Image.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a logical disconnect between by database structure and my Entity model.

The productImages table supports a *-1 mapping therefore the Products POCO class needs to have a collection of ProductImages. Then the entities need to be configured as follows:

```
public class ProductImagesMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductImage>
{
        //Other field and key configuration...

        this.HasRequired(t=>t.Image).WithRequiredDependent();

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Product)
        .WithMany(t => t.ProductImage)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.SKU);
}

public class ProductImage
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string SKU{ get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Features = new List<Feature>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SKU{ get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

I struggled with trying to configure this relationship in the ProductMap class (as Products in the parent/mater table), it was not until configured it from the ProductImages class that it worked so my two open questions are:

1) What rules determine which entity drives the relationship configuration?

2) Is there a way I can configure the Products POCO class to have an ICollection Images property and bypass the ProductImage entity all-together as ProductImage only serves as a link table between products and images?